# How can I delete chars from string with regex?

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks like

```
7766. Иванов Иван Иванович*, 01.01.1950 г.р. , Г. НАЛЬЧИК КАБАРДИНО-БАЛКАРСКОЙ РЕСПУБЛИКИ;
```

I need to remove the first id numbers(`'7766. '`) of that string. Try `delete` method with a regular expression: `delete('/(\d+\.\s)/')`

Tried many ways - nothing works... only removes points in string.

Comment: `s.gsub(/^(\d+\. )/, '')`

Comment: @DaveNewton: since we only replace one occurrence, `sub` is a better fit. Also, an alternative: `s[/^(\d+\. )/] = ''`. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oops, yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sub` method, like this:

```
my_string = "7766. Иванов Иван Иванович*, 01.01.1950 г.р. , Г. НАЛЬЧИК КАБАРДИНО-БАЛКАРСКОЙ РЕСПУБЛИКИ;"

my_string.sub(/\d+\. /, "")
#=> "Иванов Иван Иванович*, 01.01.1950 г.р. , Г. НАЛЬЧИК КАБАРДИНО-БАЛКАРСКОЙ РЕСПУБЛИКИ;"
```